# Saving scores in winfoms game

Tags: c#, database, winforms, visual-studio-2010

This is the first time I am making a game in winforms c#. I have a memory game and I want to save the scores so whenever a button "Show Scores" is clicked, it will list the 10 top scores.

The only thing I want to ask you is if this is only possible with connecting the winform with databases or is there another way?

Comment: How you save it is up to you.  You can use a local database, shared server database, local text/xml file, etc...

Comment: There are lots of ways to do this.  I would recommend looking at [Using Application Settings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397750%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: depends what kind of data you want to save, if you just want to store numbers, you could as well store them in a text file on each line

Comment: I would use a database because of all the capabilities of SQL. You have a very specific requirement, and altogether would probably only require ~15 lines of code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well there's many ways to sava your data :

- Xml or Text file
- local Database

Here's a good example on how to save game data from [Saving Data to a Save Game File](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8bh11f1k.aspx)

- Shared server database : I would suggest either using [SQL Server Compact Edition](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=17876) or [SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/).
  Microsoft SQL Server Compact 4.0 is a free, embedded database that software developers can use for building ASP.NET websites and Windows desktop applications.

Comment: Which way is better? Because I need this game to be able to show the scores on any computer, not only on mine. I don't know how to import a database inside a winform or even if that is possible.

Comment: then you need to save your data on a shared server database and like that everyone can see all the saved scores

Comment: if you need help we can discuss more

Comment: Well I've been trying to find more about this on the internet. Can I create shared server database or is it something that is bought?

Comment: I would suggest either using SQL Server Compact Edition or SQLite.